# Libgdx 3D - Point Light shows black box & rect (PointLight not working)

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, shader, lighting

I am creating a 3d scene currently a box and rect, and trying to enable lighting.

> When i create a PointLight and add it to Environment everything turns to  black color?

all i want to do is create a 3d scene and enable point light, like a sun or rays coming from a point and shading the objects.

Code:

```
environment = new Environment();
environment.add(new PointLight().set(1f, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 20f, 100f));

modelBatch=new ModelBatch();
```

..

```
square=new ModelBuilder().createBox(300,300,300,new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
squareinst=new ModelInstance(square);
squareinst.transform.setTranslation(-500,0,0);
```

--

```
sprites.get(0).setRotationY(sprites.get(0).getRotationY() + 1f);
sprites.get(1).setRotationY(sprites.get(1).getRotationY() - 1f);
squareinst.transform.rotate(1,0,0,1);

modelBatch.begin(camera);
for(Sprite3D sp:sprites)// has 3d rect models
     sp.draw(modelBatch,environment);
modelBatch.render(squareinst,environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

PointLight turning everything black
[image]

Without using environment or lights
[image]

as per my investigation, here if pointlight is not working then everything should be black as currently, because the environment needs light, it works fine with Directional light (only the backface of rect is black even after rotations, i don't know why)

libgdx version 1.6.1 - android studio
i checked it on both android device and desktop

please i really need to get this PointLight working, i don't know if it will take a custom shader, if so please guide me to some links because i am not experienced in shaders. I also read about PointLight not working on some device or not working in opengl 2.0 enabled, but i am not sure.

I tried a lot of thing and values. I know about Ambient Light but that has no use to my case. Directional light also has limited usage (can be used as a fallback if this doesn't work).

---

Edit:

Its working now, check the answer below:

- if you are using big camera size or big model size, please try adding more zeros to the pointlight intensity until the light is visible.
  [image]

Comment: Your units are way too big for that light intensity. Use units around 1 instead of 300 and 500.

Comment: Hello @Xoppa i tried all these values and light positions too, i started using 0-1f range, then i used 100f because it was written in libgdx tests, i even tried changing these values before posting this comment, but still same result.

Comment: Please link to the test that suggest that so it can be fixed. Perhaps start with something that does work and modify it for your needs. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/LightsTest.java.

Comment: @Xoopa yes this is the same test link, i will try their java file. If possible please post any of your working examples.

Comment: That one uses values around one and I can assure it works, because I made it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Xoppa you are the boss, this example is working, i tried it.

Still i am a bit confused about the proper use, your example has a lot of transforms and a renderable pLight. It will be awesome if you can redirect me to some guide or explain it, since you made the example, please post as an answer so i can mark it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that shows a point light being rotated around a sphere:

```
public class PointLightTest extends ApplicationAdapter {
    ModelBatch modelBatch;
    Environment environment;
    PerspectiveCamera camera;
    CameraInputController camController;
    PointLight pointLight;
    Model model;
    ModelInstance instance;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        camera.position.set(5f, 5f, 5f);
        camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
        camController = new CameraInputController(camera);
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
        environment.add(pointLight = new PointLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 2f, 0f, 0f, 10f));

        ModelBuilder mb = new ModelBuilder();
        model = mb.createSphere(1f, 1f, 1f, 20, 10, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)), Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
        instance = new ModelInstance(model);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        camController.update();
        pointLight.position.rotate(Vector3.Z, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 90f);
        modelBatch.begin(camera);
        modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        model.dispose();
        modelBatch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Note that the light needs to be outside the model and within the range for it to light the model. Try what happens when you gradually move the light away from the model or towards the model. The Renderable in that other example was used to visualize this location of the light.

Comment: Thanks, you made it look super easy. I was doing the same thing earlier, but the light position, intensity and model size values were not all appropiate. My camera size was 2845x1600 and model size was 300x300 so the light intensity was too small, i changed the light intensity to 30000 and then it was visible. Thanks once again and have a good day.

Comment: You really should use values around one (`1f`). Using those large values might (will) cause problems later on, e.g. floating point precision errors can accumulate very quickly in matrix math (which is what is used behind the scenes).

Comment: You are right, in case of a 1:1 camera size of any ratio like 1.x:1.x of screen size, your light is visible, but when i create a 2560x1440 or 2845x1600 canvas for camera size in games, the light is not visible on large objects, it is only visible with large intensity values.